# jQuery: Making synchronous requests properly

Tags: jquery, ajax, synchronous

Ok, so I need to open a dialog (jQuery UI) before performing the actual AJAX request and depending on what the user chooses, continue with the AJAX request or simply do nothing.

Unfortunately the function seems to be returning early and ignores the synchronous request completely. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
function saveSomeStuff(value) {
    var returnvalue = this.revert;

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        draggable: false,
        buttons: {
            "OK": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                returnvalue = $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: config.someUrl,
                    async: false,
                    data : {/* some data */}
                }).responseText;
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    }); 

    return returnvalue;

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: config.someUrl,
        async: true,
        data : {/* some data */},
        success : function (data) { *YOUR LOGIC HERE*}
})
```

P.S. Avoid synchronous requests everywhere.

Comment: What do you mean by "P.S. Avoid synchronous requests everywhere."?

Comment: I mean, that synchronous requests is very bad practices.

Comment: It would be useful if you would qualify your statement about synchronous requests being bad. Where did you hear this? Can you post a link to a good discussion of this issue? What are the reasons for it being bad? Is it a security thing? A cross platform thing? etc...

Comment: @griZZZly8 I actually read "Avoid asynchronous.." that's why I asked :D.

Comment: @Billy Moon Sync ajax request freezes the whole browser. So, if your server can send the answer to request only anter 10 seconds, then user CAN'T DO ANYTHING for this 10 seconds.

Comment: For future readers, AJAX is asynchronous. Please don't try to make it synchronous. Using 'async:false' will lock the browser until the request completes. This is not the expected behavior in all cases I guess. You could use BlockUI or Queue your other incoming requests in order to make the request act like synchronous.

Comment: There is actually one situation in which 'SJAX' is important: on window.unload(). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Irreplaceability_of_the_synchronous_use